# ExtJs - How to style textarea text?

Tags: css, extjs, styles, extjs4.1

I got a textarea in ExtJs 4.1 and want to modify the font family and size.

```
   style    : 'font-family: courier new, font-size: 8px'
   style    : {
     'fontFamily'   : 'courier new',
     'fontSize'     : '8px'
   }
```

I also tried like this:

```
oTextarea.el.applyStyles({
            'font-family'  : 'verdana',
            'font-size'    : '8px'
         });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be using fieldStyle of the config for TextArea field component:

```
fieldStyle: {
     'fontFamily'   : 'courier new',
     'fontSize'     : '8px'
   }
```

Or if the field already exists, use the `setFieldStyle` function of the field component.